# How to do a HTTP HEAD request from the windows command line?

Tags: windows, http, command-line, windows-vista

What's the best way (or tool) on the Windows (Vista) command line to get size and modification time for a file on a remote webserver, without downloading it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux, I often use curl with the --head parameter. It is available for several operating systems, including Windows.

[edit] related to the answer below, gknw.net is currently down as of February 23 2012. Check curl.haxx.se for updated info.

Comment: Thanks! http://www.gknw.net/mirror/curl/win32/curl-7.19.0-ssl-sspi-zlib-static-bin-w32.zip has a statically linked version for Win32 that worked even better than wget.

Answer (score 11):

There is a [Win32 port of wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) that works decently.

PowerShell's `Invoke-WebRequest -Method Head` would work as well.

Answer (score 10):

If you cannot install aditional applications, then you can telnet (you will need to install this feature for your windows 7 by following [this](http://www.fettesps.com/windows-7-enable-telnet/)) the remote server:

```
TELNET server_name 80
```

followed by:

```
HEAD /virtual/directory/file.ext
```

or

```
GET /virtual/directory/file.ext
```

depending on if you want just the header (HEAD) or the full contents (GET)

Comment: Does this work for https? I tried port 443 to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

1) See the headers that come back from a GET request

```
wget --server-response -O /dev/null http://....
```

1a) Save the headers that come back from a GET request

```
wget --server-response -o headers -O /dev/null http://....
```

2) See the headers that come back from GET HEAD request

```
wget --server-response --spider http://....
```

2a) Save the headers that come back from a GET HEAD request

```
wget --server-response --spider -o headers http://....
```

- David

Comment: (a) There is no  `/dev/null` on Windows. (b) I'm not sure why you include the first two options as they said they want to issue a *HEAD* request, not a *GET*. Why download stuff you'll never use, especially if it might be large.

Answer (score 1):

I'd download [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and run a telnet session on port 80 to the webserver you want

```
HEAD /resource HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

You could alternatively download [Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) and try LWP's HEAD command. Or write your own script.